# Explanation required for @RegExp annotation in spring validator framework

Tags: regex, spring

I am working on an application where most of the form validation are done using spring validator framework and regular expression. For all the form fields which should be numeric , validation is done using below annonations

```
@RegExp(value="\\d{0,3}")
@Lenght(min=3)
private String postalCode;
```

I am not sure what is getting achieved here using RegExp annotation.
It would be great help if someone can explain this me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression says that the postalcode must match zero to 3 digits.